# AJAX timeout on live search with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hello how do I set a timer? I tried timeout: 3000 but it doesn't work this is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#Name").keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
        timeout: 3000,
        type: "POST",
        url: "search2.php",
        data:'name='+$(this).val(),
        })
        .fail(function() {
            console.log("error");
        }).success(function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
});
```

It keeps calling the ajax call for every character I type.

Thanks already

Comment: Have you checked what `timeout` does mean in `$.ajax()` parameters before trying it?

Comment: Timeout in jquery: Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request. Ref to: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `setTimeout` to delay the search, something like:

```
var timeout;
$("#Name").keyup(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(timeout) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search2.php",
                data: 'name=' + $this.val(),
            })
            .fail(function() {
                console.log("error");
            }).success(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            });
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: It looks more like OP wants the exact opposite of this (ie. `if(timeout) /*do nothing*/ else setTimeout()`)

Comment: He states `It keeps calling the ajax call for every character I type.`, my understanding is that he wants it to search after he's finished typing.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a timeout to debounce the keyup event, e.g:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var timeout;
    $("#Name").keyup(function () {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(livesearch.bind(this), 3000); 
        // or to support IE8: timeout = setTimeout($.proxy(livesearch, this), 3000);
    });

    function livesearch() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "search2.php",
            data: 'name=' + this.value,
        }).fail(function () {
            console.log("error");
        }).success(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
});
```